# Table shelf patent US5653413

Tags: us621888

I am curious about this product and wondering if this patent is still valid even though it is over a hundred years old.

In reference to the patent: [US621888](https://www.google.com/patents/US621888)

Comment: Both patents have expired. The US5653413 "Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR " as is indicated in public PAIR. The US621888 has expired a long time ago.

Comment: @john If you have an answer, please post it below.Thanks.

Comment: @JustinSasse please mark the question as answered if the answer is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Both patents have expired. The [US5653413](https://www.google.com/patents/US5653413) "Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR " as is indicated in [public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). The [US621888](http://www.google.com/patents/US621888) has expired a long time ago. Haven't found any specific indication of that but according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent_in_the_United_States) the longest period for patent validity was 21 years and it's way beyond that now.